# How to do different actions based on different image's locations (A digital book with traditional look)

Tags: c#, image, xaml, image-processing

I'm new to stackoverflow, and hope my question be in the right place ?

I'm going to make an application for a book which look the same as in paper. So I have images of all the pages of the book.

The problem is, I want when the user clicks/taps on any sentence with a dot at end, some details about the sentence appear (i.e. translation of the sentence in another language)

Something like this:
[image]

I want to know how can I implement this? a better way than the terrible-cutting-every-sentence of a 500 page book!

Comment: Do you have some examples?

Comment: Do you mean, you are storing each page as a bitmap?

Comment: @StaWho yes, that is. I want it to be exactly the same as in paper. but also I have a database of the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely what you've been expecting but a few cues.

Unless you do some OCR to recognize/split your text I don't really see how you'd detect from an image sentences (someone correct me if I'm wrong) and their bounds for highlighting them or providing a visual cue; so I assume you'll use some OCR along with your images. (providing it's good enough to return the regions of chars/sentences so you can provide visual cues and pick the associated translation for that sentence)

Here you have some links to OCR libraries that are free to use :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744966/any-open-source-c-sharp-ocr-library

[The best .NET OCR API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847154/the-best-net-ocr-api)

When you're done OCR-ing you now have your book as a string and you'd want to split it:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(_text, @"[A-Z].*?\.");
string[] strings = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(s => s.Value).ToArray();
```

(the regex *roughly* does that task, it will need some tweaks such as handling paragraphs)

**The rest of my answer is not what you've been expecting**, I'm posting it here anyway as that's what I've created while answering your question, you might find it useful to have it along your bitmaps or not; *so feel free to skip it.* We could argue about its usefulness, here a few arguments on why you'd like it : less exhausting to read as you can set the font size and you can search inside which IMO is a great feature.

So here it is :

I've used a FlowDocumentReader to represent the sentences. Here, I have used a Run and a ToolTip but you could have used an Hyperlink which would open some web site instead.

```
IEnumerable<Paragraph> paragraphs = strings.Select(s => new Paragraph(new Run(s) {ToolTip = "Translated text"}));
document.Blocks.AddRange(paragraphs);
```

And the associated XAML:

```
<FlowDocumentReader>
    <FlowDocumentReader.Document>
        <FlowDocument x:Name="document" />
    </FlowDocumentReader.Document>
</FlowDocumentReader>
```

Result :

[image]

**EDIT**

That's why I suggested you to use OCR, to get the regions of the words, nothing else.

[image]

(taken from http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/)

```
var tesseract = new Tesseract();
var bitmap = new Bitmap("snap00110.png");
List<Word> doOcr = tesseract.DoOCR(bitmap, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), bitmap.Size));
foreach (var word in doOcr)
{
    var region = new Rectangle(word.Left, word.Top, word.Right - word.Left, word.Bottom - word.Top);
}
```

When you have regions of words you will be able achieve what you want.

Note : I've been the trying the library, you might have to rebuild it, if you are under .NET 4.0

Comment: merci @Aybe, I already have whole characters, sentences and even I know they are in which pages, so I can skip OCRing.. the main problem is knowing their location in the page... +1